# How do I resolve this issue in Google Maps Autocomplete in my Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I am creating a rails application for a taxi booking platform that requires entering a pickup point and a drop point. I have included the following script in my application.html.erb for this purpose within the header tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var placeSearch,autocomplete;
  function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), { types: [ 'geocode' ] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
    });

    autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete2'), { types: [ 'geocode' ] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
});
  }
  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in component_form) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = "";
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components.length; j++) {
      var att = place.address_components[j].types[0];
      if (component_form[att]) {
        var val = place.address_components[j][component_form[att]];
        document.getElementById(att).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have then used this js as follows in my  tag:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag ("Pickup Location: ") %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :pickup_loc, nil, :id => "autocomplete", :placeholder => "Enter your pickup location" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag ("Drop Location: ") %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :drop_loc, nil, :id => "autocomplete2", :placeholder => "Enter your dropoff location" %>
  </div>
```

While the autocomplete feature seems to work, the result of the autocomplete feature seems to be a subset of the results that google maps gives. For ex, when I put "Asian GPR..." as my search query in my application, it doesn't show the Asian GPR Multiplex as the option:

[image]

However, when I use the same query string in Google Maps, I get the desired result:

[image]

I have tried to search a lot on this, but couldn't find a solution. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) it says:

> An array of types specifies an explicit type or a type collection, as
>   listed in the supported types below. If nothing is specified, all
>   types are returned. In general only a single type is allowed. The
>   exception is that you can safely mix the geocode and establishment
>   types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no
>   types.

So I guess you only need to delete the type option as follows:

```
function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
    });

    autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete2'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
});
```

or you can add the establishment type:

```
    function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), { types: [ 'geocode', 'establishment' ] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
    });

    autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete2'), { types: [ 'geocode', 'establishment' ] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete2, 'place_changed', function() {
      fillInAddress();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Badoo...it works, but how do I calculate the distance between my origin and the destination places? Earlier, I was using GoogleDirections.new(params[:pickup_loc], params[:drop_loc]).distance_in_miles, but after removing the type option, all my distances show 0. Do I need to update my distance formula as well? How?

Comment: Well that's another question. The best would be to add [the computeDistanceBetween method provided by the google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical).This is going to calculate a straight line between two latitudes and longitudes:
`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
    a, b
);`
  or you can check out [the distance matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) but this is more a travel distance calculator.